# No internet ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I have a xiaomi air 13 intel 7, I installed ubuntu 14.04 lts along with windows 10, the windows side can connect ethernet and to wifi but ubuntu's side can't, what can I do ? Thanks in advance Ps: I am a new user

I installed http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.14/linux-headers-4.10.14-041014_4.10.14-041014.201705031501_all.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.14/linux-headers-4.10.14-041014-generic_4.10.14-041014.201705031501_amd64.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.14/linux-image-4.10.14-041014-generic_4.10.14-041014.201705031501_amd64.deb install 
And also tried to installlinux-firmware_1.173.1.tar.gz but couldn't install this last one,  commands like. /configure says its not found

So  I still don't  have internet conection

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This problem is fixed I installed a new deb file Instead of the last one and it worked, now I have internet